Scroll a word in a label
I have a long text in a Label that is in a ScrollView, and I would like to scroll a specific word to make it visible.
Is there a way to do this please?
Thanks

You can set the HeightRequest of the ScrollView  so that you can scroll the line.

@liyu OP wants to scroll and highlight a particular word in the whole text block.

As far as I know there's no way to scroll contents of a long text chunk located in a Label to highlight a specific word in it.
I do not know particular details of your task, but probably it would be acceptable to convert your text block to list of elements and have a CollectionView to represent it. And then use method ScrollTo(int index) like that:
collectionView.ScrollTo(12);

More details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/scrolling

A low-brow solution would be to rewrite the Label.Text, e.g.
// Default
label.Text = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";

// Scroll to "fox"
label.Text = "fox jumped over the lazy dog.";


The other way to do it is to convert label to Editor, set its IsReadOnly to true and try to play with CursorPosition, which should bring certain text into view.
The other benefit is that Editor allows for selection of the text.
Haven't tried it, so take this at ur own risk.
